# Why an image from my local folder is not loaded in img tag in HTML while the same image works fine with background-image in css with same URL path

Tags: html, css, sass, node-sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQocX.png)When using the img tag, the alt text is shown, and using background-image property works totally fine.

## HTML Code

```
<div class="topbar">
    <img src="../../assets/images/p-icon.jpg" alt='Profile Pic' />
</div>
```

---

## CSS Code

```
.topbar {
    img {
        background-image: url('../../assets/images/p-icon.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your CSS in a subdirectory, perchance? I've done that plenty of times when copying over paths.

If your CSS is in a subdirectory (e.g. `/assets/css/style.css`) and your HTML is in a parent directory (e.g. `/index.html`), then you're in need of a path change.

Besides that, there's no obvious reason it wouldn't work with the information provided.

Comment: Both CSS file and JSX file(HTML) are in same folder and image is placed in parent folder.